# Swift 2.0 asking for unused framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I am in the middle of converting from Swift 1.2 to 2.0 right now and getting a lot of errors.
One error I am not understanding is that the project is saying "Bolts" framework cannot be found when I did not install. The error message says

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool:
>   can't open file:
>   /Users/(folder name)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/(project name)-hbmgkordvxgsspgvgfvyvipkmmdi/Build/Intermediates/SwiftMigration/(project name)/Products/Debug-iphoneos/(project name).app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts
>   (No such file or directory)

I checked my podfile and there was no "Bolts" in it. Just to make sure I installed Bolts again through cocoapods and built the project. I still got the same error. One weird thing I found about cocoapods is that the terminal said bolts file is successfully installed when I did not include in my podfile. Please refer to the pics below. (Please disregard all pods starting with #)

[image]////////////////////////////////////////

[image]

Any help will be appreaciated!

Comment: Check your Podfile.lock for more info. Probably it is dependency of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bolts` is an automatic dependency of `Parse`.

Try performing project clean using `cmd+shift+K` then rebuild again.

Comment: Apparantly, my parse pod was not updated tho the latest version and was causing problem in swift 2.0. It is solved. Thnx.